# Customise static tableview Header - Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, header

I am trying to customize static UITableViewController section header with UITableViewCell.

I could successfully cusomise section header in dynamic tableView by using the below set of code,

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell")
        headerCell?.textLabel?.text = "Section \(section + 1)"
        headerCell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blue
        return headerCell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
```

But, couldn't work for static tableview.
How to customise section header with static tableView

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by static tableView?

Comment: @Gkolunia: There are to type of tableview static cells and dynamic cells. I am using Static cell for UITableView

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you should return a `UIView`, not a `UITableViewCell` in `viewForHeaderInSection` method.

Also you should keep an instance of header cell for future use (like modifying its view)

Create a field in your `TableViewController` like this:

```
private var headerViewCell: UITableViewCell?
```

and then in the `viewForHeaderInSection` do this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell")
    headerCell?.textLabel?.text = "Section \(section + 1)"
    headerCell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blue
    self.headerViewCell = headerCell
    return headerCell?.contentView
}
```

Comment: I could you 'UITableViewCell' for Customise section header. but it is not working in static tableview

Comment: it return an optional view and tablview cell is also a subclass of uiview and upcasting in implicit so you can return uitableview cell here

Comment: I assume you will edit the header cell view such as text color, text label or whatever. in this case wired things will happen! such as disappearing header etc. I experienced this type of issues and all of them was because I returned the `UITableViewCell` itself! So instead of down vote, please do some research. beside, it's nice to use Google Translate

Answer (score -1):

I think you should unwrap cell when using `dequeueReusableCell`.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell") as! HeaderCell   //  here header cell is your cell's custom class
        headerCell.textLabel.text = "Section \(section + 1)"
        headerCell.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.blue
        return headerCell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
```

Comment: it return an optional view and tablview cell is also a subclass of uiview and upcasting in implicit so you can return uitableview cell here there no need for unwraping

Comment: well i for custom headerview you need to return a custom cell or a custom view